# Understanding np.where for multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand [numpy's example of the multidimensional array where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function:

```
np.where([[True, False], [True, True]],
...          [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
...          [[9, 8], [7, 6]])
array([[1, 8],
       [3, 4]])
```

How does the condition `[[True, False], [True, True]]` correspond to the output `[[1, 8],[3, 4]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code above can be made more readable like below

```py
cond = [[True, False], [True, True]]
arr1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
arr2 = [[9, 8], [7, 6]]

np.where(cond, arr1, arr2)
```

It can be described in sentence as, for each element of `cond` if the element is `True` take corresponding element from `arr1` else take corresponding element from `arr2`.

So basically it is doing element wise `arr1 if cond else arr2`. Here is how you can see it using loop

```py
for sub_cond, sub_arr1, sub_arr2 in zip(cond,arr1,arr2):
    for c, a1, a2 in zip(sub_cond, sub_arr1, sub_arr2):
        print(f"{a1} if {c}=True else {a2}")
        print(a1 if c else a2)
```

*Result*

```
1 if True=True else 9
1
2 if False=True else 8
8
3 if True=True else 7
3
4 if True=True else 6
4
```